# Where do I start with making my own assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to make my own assembler (as in NASM, MASM, etc.), but I don't know where to start. I understand x86 assembly, but I don't know much about how assemblers work. Where should I start? Google isn't helping my in this instance. Is there any sites that would be useful in learning this?

Comment: Could you perhaps post a comment instead of silently voting to close?

Comment: Also, why isn't it letting me tag it 'assembler'?

Comment: Won't one of you say why you are voting to close?

Comment: What's the architecture you're building on top of, or is it all custom? (I'm not the one trying to close it, BTW)

Comment: @JoeCoder x86, I'll add that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An assembler (not to be confused with a linker) is a program that does two things:

- It replaces labels with actual addresses
- It converts the memotechnical names into opcodes and stores them on an so called object file.

All you need is an lookup table for which maps names to opcodes. It should be quite straight forward to do it.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm looking for a table. Google isn't helping. That's what I need. EDIT: That's not all of what I need, though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to translate the assmbler instructions into machine code, calculate addresses and put everything into a object file. You don't need to do everything in one pass.

If you are looking for an opcode table, a good starting point would be http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html or http://www.sandpile.org/ . Of course the official intel and amd documentation can be used too.

For the object file format, it depends what you want to do with the code. A pure binary can not be used for much more than a boot sector, a kernel or a DOS *.com program as Alex pointed out. For everything else you will need relocation information in the object file.

Comment: DOS .COM programs didn't have relocation info because they occupied one segment and started with all segment registers pointing to it. With virtual to physical address translation you can similarly avoid relocation for the main module of every process that lives in its own virtual address space (just like that .COM segment).

Comment: @Alex: Thanks, I forgot that.